# How to construct this sentence: "The manager of the representative"?

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives

How can I construct this sentence "The manager of the representative"?
I mean about something like this: "representative's manager"

The full sentence is:

> The manager of the representative said to us "Now, We are going to new way".

Comment: Not quite sure what the problem is. Do you mean like "The *representative's manager* said to us "Now, we are going *a* new way".? Its pretty much what you said.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. 
First of all, I mean how to constrict these five words into three only: 
“The manager of the representative”. 
Second, I'd like to know by the way of the following sentence is correct grammatically: 
"The manager of the representative said to us "Now, We are going to new way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To condense this phrase "The manager of the representative" to three words:

> The representative's manager

So putting this into your example:

> **The representative's manager** said to us "Now, *we* are going *a* new way".

The other changes:
1) "*we*" is not capitalized.
2) The usual way to say this is "*going a new way*", meaning going in a new (business) direction.
Possibly you could say "*going to a new way*", but *way* is a countable noun so an article is needed.